# How can I color seaborn plots according to the hex code in one column?

Tags: python, seaborn

My pandas dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
Year    Name    RGB     Percentage
1949    Blue    0055BF  9.356725
1949    Red     C91A09  20.467836
1949    Yellow  F2CD37  10.526316
1950    Blue    0055BF  45.454545
1950    Red     C91A09  13.636364
1953    Blue    0055BF  7.142857
1953    Red     C91A09  28.571429
1953    Yellow  F2CD37  21.428571
```

I am plotting a line plot:

```
sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Percentage', hue='Name', data=df)
```

But I want to color the lines according to the hex codes in column RGB. 
The plots for 'Blue' shall have the color `0055BF`, Red `C91A09` and Yellow `F2CD37`.

What's the best way to automatically color the lines based on the hex codes in column RGB?

Comment: `sns.lineplot(x='Year', y='Percentage', hue='#'+df['RGB'], data=df)`

Comment: Or `sns.lineplot(..., hue='Name', palette={'Blue': '#0055BF', 'Red': '#C91A09', 'Yellow': '#F2CD37'})` which generates a more logic default legend

Comment: Thanks, I am going to work with the hue workaround, as I don't need the legend.